# Как передать ссылку на ViewPager в другой класс?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter, android-customview

У меня есть класс CustomView. В этом классе логика такова, что при нажатии на кнопку, происходит переход на следующую страницу ViewPager. Т.е. мне нужно, что бы переход на следующую станицу ViewPager у меня осуществлялся и посредством смахивания вправо (это у меня работает) и посредством нажатия на кнопку. В классе CustomView я получаю ошибку  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method `'androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager Activity.getViewPager()' on a null object reference`
Я не могу понять, как мне правильно сослаться на объект ViewPager, который у меня в классе Activity.

activity class:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private ViewPager viewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return viewPager;
    }
}
```

custom class:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Button button;
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
   Activity activity;
    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               activity.getViewPager().setCurrentItem( 1, true);
               }
        })
```

Comment: а инициализация переменной activity есть в коде?

Comment: я уже поняла, что создавать объект в активити - это плохая практика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно передавать никаких ссылок. Это очень плохая практика.

Я бы создал внутри вашего *CustomView* интерфейс вроде такого:

```
interface PageInterractor {
    
    void setPosition(int position);
}
```

Этот интерфейс должна реализовать ваша *Activity/Fragment*. И в этом методе вы будете уже внутри *Activity/Fragment* переключать страницы вашего пейджера.

Внутри вашей *CustomView* вы создаете экземпляр этого интерфейса

```
private PageInterractor interractor;
```

И сеттер для него

```
public void setPageInterractor(PageInterractor interractor) {
  
    this.interractor = interractor;
}
```

И в вашем клик листенере

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               interractor.setPosition(1);
               }
        })
```

В чем проблема в вашем подходе?

Во-первых вы напрямую обращаетесь к активити, а это значит, что вы не сможете переместить эту View куда-то еще, так чтоб не менять код.

Во-вторых вы храните ссылку на ViewPager, а значит ваша View работает ТОЛЬКО с ViewPager-ом, а если вы захотите поменять к примеру на RecyclerView то у вас будут проблемы.

В-третьих ваша View отвечает за то, что отвечать не должна. Вы не сможете ее переиспользовать где-либо еще.

**UPD**

Если же вам так необходимо передавать экземпляр ViewPager внутрь вашей CustomView то сделать это просто.

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    // other code

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public void setPager(ViewPager pager) {
        viewPager = pager;
    }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // other code

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(pager == null) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException("Need set ViewPager with method setPager() before use it"
               } else {
                   // do something with pager
               }
        })
    }
}
```

В активити после того как вы вызвали метод findViewById на вашем педжере вызовете метод

```
customView.setPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Можно ли как-то передать ссылку `CustomView` в `customPagerAdapter` , что бы адаптер уведомил `CustomView` о достижении последней страницы ? т е как-то подключиться к экземпляру `ViewPager `тут : `viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)`

Comment: а если у меня во `ViewPager` ,например, 10 страниц, я бы хотела сделать так : `viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1` т е все равно нужна ссылка на `ViewPager`

Comment: Нет. Вам не нужна ссылка на адаптер. Вам нужно просто метод в интерфейсе другой. например `void nextPage()` внутри которого вы будете делать `viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1`

Comment: По поводу первого вопроса. Чем меньше разные сущности знают друг о друге тем лучше для вас. Например если вы хотите из адаптера переключать вашу кастомную View то в адаптере есть pageChageListener (или как-то так, не помню). И в этом вот листенере в активити мы вызываете какой-то публичный метод из CustomView

Comment: Любой кейс в котором адаптер знает о вашей View или наоборот == плохой кейс. Вы не знаете что будет завтра. МОжет вам понядобится вместо адаптера написать своб View или использовать другое готовое решение. Может быть вы захотите эту View использовать на другом экране, где нет вообще адаптеров и механизм переключения страниц совершенно другой. Имея интерфейс для вас это не проблема. то что хотите сделать вы не даст вам возможности переиспользования без костылей и переделок

Comment: но тут `viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1` мне же все равно нужно ссылаться на `viewPager`. и получится ,что тут объект класса `ViewPager` будет `null`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113396/discussion-between-sergei-buvaka-and-monica).